# Postgres JSONB - query all root keys

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

PostgreSQL (13.2)

I have a table with 2 columns - timestamp and snapshot.
Snapshot consist a JSONB - dict that represent the condition of warehouse.
The data stracture is like this

```
{
    "key1": {...},
    "key2": {...},
    "key3": {...},
    "key4": {...},
    "key5": {...}
}
```

So I need to get the specific key in json that consist the data I am looking for. I also need to get a row timestamp that holds the snapshot.
How can I query this?

ps.
In python i can use smth like dict.keys and then start looping across all keys, something similiar i need here for searching the data.

pps.
also It would be interesting to know how to implement it with SQLAlchemy

[screenshot from DB viewer]

[image: 1]

Comment: This needs clarification: Where is the row timestamp stored? What is a snapshot in this context?

Comment: Laurenz, It's stored in database table, snapshot Is a JSONB dict that holds the current condition of warehouse. Check the screenshot attached bellow the question for better understanding the context. Thanks!

Comment: Does the data have to be structured like this?  Wouldn't it be better to have an array of warehouses as warehouse_name: r9 etc, then the other data in the same object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(jsonb_each()).*  selects all keys and values from jsonb field:

```
SELECT (JSONB_EACH(blocks)).*
FROM snapshots
```

then we need to get values by nested keys:

```
SELECT key AS rack_num
     , value ->> 'client_id' AS client_id
     , value ->> 'timestamp' AS _TIMESTAMP
FROM (
      SELECT (JSONB_EACH(blocks)).*
      FROM snapshots
     ) AS t
```

and finally, aggregate the results:

```
SELECT rack_num
       , MIN(_TIMESTAMP) AS appearance_time
FROM (
      SELECT KEY                   AS rack_num
           , VALUE ->> 'client_id' AS client_id
           , VALUE ->> 'timestamp' AS _TIMESTAMP
      FROM (
            SELECT (JSONB_EACH(blocks)).*
            FROM snapshots
           ) AS t
      ) AS racks
WHERE client_id = :client_id
GROUP BY rack_num, client_id
ORDER BY MIN(_TIMESTAMP) DESC;
```

Comment: This query just did the job done! Thanks!